# SAXParseException GeoServer SLD error

Tags: geoserver, sld

I want to change SLD of WMS layer dynamically. In SLD string I have CssParameter XML tag that has Hex color code like "#ff0000". When I post it to GeoServer I got this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber:
>   1; columnNumber: 619; XML document structures must start and end
>   within the same entity. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1;
>   columnNumber: 619; XML document structures must start and end within
>   the same entity. XML document structures must start and end within the
>   same entity

That refers to line the line that it has the `#` character. Here is the code sample:

```
var SLD = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">';
SLD += '<NamedLayer><Name>pmo:iczmoagriculturemokran</Name><UserStyle><Name>pmo:iczmoagriculturemokran</Name><Title>Green polygon</Title><Abstract>Green fill with black outline</Abstract><FeatureTypeStyle><Rule><PolygonSymbolizer><Fill><CssParameter name="fill">#ff0000</CssParameter></Fill><Stroke /></PolygonSymbolizer></Rule></FeatureTypeStyle></UserStyle></NamedLayer></StyledLayerDescriptor>';

SLD = encodeURI(SLD);
var source = layer.WMSLayer.getSource();
source.updateParams({ STYLES: undefined, SLD_BODY: SLD });
```

After encodeURI SLD turns to:

%3C?xml%20version=%221.0%22%20encoding=%22UTF-8%22?%3E%3CStyledLayerDescriptor%20version=%221.0.0%22%20xmlns=%22http://www.opengis.net/sld%22%20xmlns:ogc=%22http://www.opengis.net/ogc%22%20xmlns:xlink=%22http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink%22%20xmlns:xsi=%22http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance%22%20xsi:schemaLocation=%22http://www.opengis.net/sld%20http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd%22%3E%3CNamedLayer%3E%3CName%3Egreen%3C/Name%3E%3CUserStyle%3E%3CName%3Egreen%3C/Name%3E%3CTitle%3EGreen%20polygon%3C/Title%3E%3CAbstract%3EGreen%20fill%20with%20black%20outline%3C/Abstract%3E%3CFeatureTypeStyle%3E%3CRule%3E%3CPolygonSymbolizer%3E%3CFill%3E%3CCssParameter%20name=%22fill%22%3E#ff0000%3C/CssParameter%3E%3C/Fill%3E%3CStroke%20/%3E%3C/PolygonSymbolizer%3E%3C/Rule%3E%3C/FeatureTypeStyle%3E%3C/UserStyle%3E%3C/NamedLayer%3E%3C/StyledLayerDescriptor%3E

Comment: Your sld seems fine, can you edit the question to show what it looks like after you call encodeURI() on it.

Comment: Yeah, I edited question.

Comment: Where does the encode come from? because I think it should give you %3CCssParameter+name%3D%22fill%22%3E%23ff0000%3C%2FCssParameter%3E for the fill

Comment: It is javascript built-in. I changed # to %23 but geoserver dont respond wms layer.

Comment: next thing to check is the geoserver log when you have turned logging up to developer

Comment: The encoded URL is not the same as your example! In your example code you have `<NamedLayer><Name>pmo:iczmoagriculturemokran</Name>` but in your encoded URL you have `<NamedLayer><Name>green</Name>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can Convert Hex value of color to base 10. for example use 4359924 (BASE 10) instead of #4286f4 (BASE 16) in CssParameter tag:

```
<CssParameter name="fill">4359924</CssParameter>
```

Comment: But why does it help? Shouldn't using hex value for color be OK by the standards?